Should a note be played by the right or the left hand if the bar extends between the F and G clefs in piano?
Are the 2 (eighth notes) quavers to be played by the left or right or is it up to the player to decide? I though there would have been rests in the G clef for the right hand but I don't see any.
I got this part from a free download PDF when I was searching for 9th chords and ran into this particular download of this music school.


It's so poorly written, I wouldn't give it the time of day. Let alone worry about which hand to play it with.

Moral of the story: as a beginner  don't rely on free download sheet music.

Just from the example image, based on the eighth note beam starting on the bass clef, I would first think to play this with only my left hand. Also, the example is easy to read as a C major triad in second inversion, played broken, so it's natural to just play the chord with one hand (the left) and just break up the chord with the fingers.
I would also wonder why the person who notated it didn't just use two ledger lines above the F clef instead of splitting between clefs. There are reasons for notating like that, but the example doesn't present any of them.
You left out some important information when cropping the score. Here it is in context...

Only the 5 measure are the whole "work." There are a total of 5 such excerpts on the page. They are sort of like "five finger" exercies.
You would play the red parts with the LH and the blue with the RH. The important point is you cropped out the melodic line descending from E4 to C4! The point of such exercises is to get the hands coordinated playing short little groups of notes with no position change. The reason to notate it across the grand staff in that way is to avoid the clutter or rests that would need to be there for proper two-part writing.

Could you elaborate? What are the reasons for using that notation?

I editing the my answer, because you cropped out an important part of the notation.

If you want to see good examples of notating piano across the grand staff, try Debussy's piano music. If you are beginner, it will be hard to read. Usually the beaming of notes is the clue to which hand plays. Sometimes LH and RH are indicated to make it explicit.

This part is written as a single voice on a grand staff, which is not typical for piano sheet music.  It is meant to be an exercise on reading pitches on the staff; it does not attempt to show which hand should play what note.  So, play it however you prefer.
